# Spark SQL performance using JDBC with mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, jdbc, apache-spark

I'm using Apache Spark v2.0. Using `(var spark: **SparkSession**) spark.read.jdbc(JDBC_URL,tableName,JDBC_PROP)`, reading DataFrame.
and then used dataframe.**createOrReplaceTempView** (instead of dataframe.**registerTempTable**) connecting to mysql using JDBC

```
var readSQL = "SELECT 
    p.forum_id, 
    p.user_id, 
    DATE(p.created_at) AS activity_date, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT IF(dcm1.class_member_role_id=1, p.post_id, NULL)) AS replies_to_other_learner, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT IF(dcm1.class_member_role_id=3,p.post_id,NULL)) replies_to_instructor 
  FROM TableB" + contentId + " p 
  JOIN TableA" + contentId + " df ON df.forum_topic_id=p.forum_id 
  JOIN TableC" + contentId + " dcm ON df.class_id=dcm.class_id AND dcm.user_id=p.user_id and dcm.class_member_role_id=1 
  JOIN TableB" + contentId + " p1 ON p1.forum_id=p.forum_id AND p1.post_id=p.parent_id AND p1.user_id!=p.user_id 
  JOIN TableC" + contentId + " dcm1 ON df.class_id=dcm1.class_id AND dcm1.user_id=p1.user_id WHERE p.forum_id='" + contentId + "' GROUP BY p.forum_id, p.user_id, p.created_at"

 val table = spark.sql(readSQL)
 table.cache
```

Likewise, I have to execute others query as well, each every query take 15 min to execute, which takes too long. The same query run on mysql within milliseconds.

**Table Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE `TableA` (
  `forum_topic_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `class_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `forum_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `subforum_type_id` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `forum_max_points` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `individual_user_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_instructor_topic` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_didnt_get_forum` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_gradable` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `master_dq_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `class_folder_content_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `loudbook_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `content_annotation_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assignment_group_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `announcement_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `class_content_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`forum_topic_id`,`class_id`),
  KEY `forum_type` (`forum_type`),
  KEY `class_folder_content_id` (`class_folder_content_id`),
  KEY `class_content_id` (`class_content_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

  /*Index Information*/
---------------------

Table                    Non_unique  Key_name                 Seq_in_index  Column_name              Collation  Cardinality  Sub_part  Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment  Index_comment  
-----------------------  ----------  -----------------------  ------------  -----------------------  ---------  -----------  --------  ------  ------  ----------  -------  ---------------
TableA           0  PRIMARY                             1  forum_topic_id           A                    0    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE                               
TableA           0  PRIMARY                             2  class_id                 A                    0    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE                               
TableA           1  forum_type                          1  forum_type               A                    0    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE                               
TableA           1  class_folder_content_id             1  class_folder_content_id  A                    0    (NULL)  (NULL)  YES     BTREE                               
TableA           1  class_content_id                    1  class_content_id         A                    0    (NULL)  (NULL)  YES     BTREE                               

    CREATE TABLE `TableC` (
      `id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `class_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `course_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `user_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `class_member_role_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'parent_role_id',
      `actual_role_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'class_member_role_id',
      `joining_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `status` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `start_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `end_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `last_submitted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `last_activity_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `time_spent` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `current_score` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
      `final_score` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
      `current_grade` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      `final_grade` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      `last_time_spent_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `deactivated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `canvas_status` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`class_id`,`user_id`,`class_member_role_id`),
      KEY `class_member_role_id` (`class_member_role_id`),
      KEY `class_id` (`class_id`),
      KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='TableC'

    Table                           Non_unique  Key_name              Seq_in_index  Column_name           Collation  Cardinality  Sub_part  Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment  Index_comment  
------------------------------  ----------  --------------------  ------------  --------------------  ---------  -----------  --------  ------  ------  ----------  -------  ---------------
TableC           0  PRIMARY                          1  class_id              A                    0    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE                               
TableC           0  PRIMARY                          2  user_id               A                    0    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE                               
TableC           0  PRIMARY                          3  class_member_role_id  A                    0    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE                               
TableC           1  class_member_role_id             1  class_member_role_id  A                    0    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE                               
TableC           1  class_id                         1  class_id              A                    0    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE                               
TableC           1  user_id                          1  user_id               A                    0    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE                               


      CREATE TABLE `TableB` (
      `forum_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `parent_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
      `user_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `message` text,
      `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `updated_by` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `attachment` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`forum_id`,`post_id`,`user_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

    /*Index Information*/
    ---------------------

    Table                          Non_unique  Key_name  Seq_in_index  Column_name  Collation  Cardinality  Sub_part  Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment  Index_comment  
    -----------------------------  ----------  --------  ------------  -----------  ---------  -----------  --------  ------  ------  ----------  -------  ---------------
    TableB           0  PRIMARY              1  forum_id     A                    0    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE                               
    TableB           0  PRIMARY              2  post_id      A                    0    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE                               
    TableB           0  PRIMARY              3  user_id      A                    0    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE
```

How to increase/tune performance using spark? Also is there way to update (insert, update, query) database table using Spark or else in faster way?

Explain select gives me:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  cfc ALL PRIMARY \N  \N  \N  83  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  cm  eq_ref  PRIMARY,class_member_role_id,class_id,user_id   PRIMARY 308 34.cfc.class_id,34.cfc.created_by,const 1   Using index
1   SIMPLE  ci  ref class_id    class_id    152 34.cfc.class_id 184 Using where
```

Comment: If your query runs on mysql within milliseconds then it means Spark is bad choice for you. It will be always slower to process such queries. If you can use usually relational database for this - use it.

Comment: Sounds like you are missing some indexes.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: Cardinality=0??  Was any data in the tables when you ran those?

Comment: "TableB" + contentId -- and yet testing for that value?  p.forum_id='" + contentId + "'??  Building a database with lots of identical tables is usually a bad design; is Spark doing this?

Comment: `VARCHAR(255)`, especially as indexes, is sloppy; is Spark doing that?

Comment: Can you provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: hey @RickJames ,thanks for reply  : "TableB" + contentId , this is because we want dataframe in multi threaded environment.  our id is VARCHAR(255), thats what is required, so cant help.

Comment: The query has 5 tables; the `EXPLAIN` has 3.  ??

Comment: Table B and Table c are twice...so